# How to send file attachment to user using contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

How to build contact form 7 that send to user file (PDF,word and co on).

Is there some plugin for this?

I want to build a landing page that sends to registered user, PDF file or word as a gift.

thanks a lot!

Comment: this can be done with CF7 : https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/#local-file-attachment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem with that, it is a default function of contact form 7! Just enter the relative path with "wp-content" as root directory to the document here:

[image]

i.e.: "uploads/2017/10/example.pdf"